# Postgres: syntax error when trying to create multiple stored procedures from a single file

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am using Postgres version 13.1. I want to have a single file where I could store all stored procedures and create them in one shot. But when I put multiple stored procedures in a single file, I get the following error. What am I missing?

In my test.sql file I have the following content:

```
create or replace procedure tmp1( 
)
language plpgsql as
$$
declare
  l_count integer;
begin
  select 1 into l_count;
  raise info 'count: %', l_count;
end;
$$

create or replace procedure tmp2( 
)
language plpgsql as
$$
declare
  l_count integer;
begin
  select 1 into l_count;
  raise info 'count: %', l_count;
end;
$$
```

If I only have the first procedure it gets created and I can call it successfully. But the moment I have the second identical procedure with a different name, it gives me an error as follows (when run from psql):

```
psql=> \i test.sql
psql:test.sql:23: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "create"
LINE 12: create or replace procedure tmp2(
```

Comment: Semicolon should be after the whole `create procedure/function` statement (as for any other statements in scripts) and it is not necessary at the end of the body: `create function ... as $$ begin ...end $$;`

Answer (score 0):

OK - right after posting I tried putting a ";" after the end of first procedure and it works